# Getting weird result for sql select operation

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a table users and i am trying to select list of users from same state "say ontario" the query runs successfully but logs/prints in console this weird results like
[com.entities.Users@4626d5e5, com.entities.Users@138da184] for the select operation performed by the following query:

```
return session.getCurrentSession().createQuery(" FROM Users e WHERE e.state = :state").setParameter("state", state).list();
```

also tried with this query below and still the same result:

```
" from Users as o where o.state= '" + state +"'"
```

Comment: your question is unclear,,,

Comment: nothing is weird..its working as expected you are getting list of users as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some languages, if you handle an object as an string, the object gets displayed as something like this: `[com.entities.Users@4626d5e5, com.entities.Users@138da184]`

Somewhere in your code you handle the list as an string which displays the list as the string you mentioned.